# opencv kmeans clustering wrong output

Tags: opencv, k-means

I am trying to implement kmeans clustering on images in openCV (using C). Instead of the clustered image resulting in some color layers, the output is pretty weird. I have also tried to debug the code, but couldn't understand where it may have gone wrong.

Here is the input and output images.

[image]

The right one is the output and the left one is the input image.

Here is the code:

```
image = cvLoadImage( "pic65.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
sample = cvCreateMat( image->height*image->width, 5, CV_32FC1 );
clusters = cvCreateMat( image->height*image->width, 1, CV_32SC1 );

data = (uchar *)image->imageData;
for(i=0;i<image->height;i++)
{
                            for(j=0;j<image->width;j++)
                            {
                            cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 0, i);
                            cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 1, j);
                            b = data[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels +0];
                            g = data[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels +1];
                            r = data[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels +2];
                            cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 2, b);
                            cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 3, g);
                            cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 4, r);
                            k++;
                            }
}
count = get_clusters();

cvKMeans2(sample,count,clusters,cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0 ));

for (x = 0; x < image->height; x++)
{
for (y = 0; y < image->width; y++)
{
    index = x * image->width + y;
    cluster_index = cvGetReal2D(clusters,index,0);
    data[x*image->widthStep + y*image->nChannels +0] = cl[cluster_index][0];
    data[x*image->widthStep + y*image->nChannels +1] = cl[cluster_index][2];
    data[x*image->widthStep + y*image->nChannels +2] = cl[cluster_index][2];
}
}
```

The get_clusters method returns the number of color clusters in the input image depending on a threshold value which is 30 in this case. If its required I can also provide you with the code of get_clusters, but I think its correct.

Can someone please point out where it has gone wrong. Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:My desired output is given below:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The output seems prety consistent with your code: cluster (x,y,r,g,b). Geographic neighbors with similar colors get in the same cluster. Except you didn't define cl.

Comment: Actually cl is the individual colors of the clusters that I have obtained from the get_clusters method.

Comment: Besides I want to cluster the image in such a way such that there is no shades of different colors. So that I can get individual color layers corresponding to a particular object.
I am editing the question so that the desired output is clear to everyone.

Comment: You want image segmentation. You could change get_clusters to compute the cluster color as the average of original pixels within the cluster to get better visual result. Then you could try to multiply (x,y) or (r,g,b) you feed to k-means to give more importance to colors or locality. Also, you can add post-processing to merge neighboring clusters of similar color.

Comment: In your output I think you just clustered individual pixels (i.e. reduced the number of colors). You don't need to feed (x,y) to k-means for that, just (r,g,b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging on your "desired output" image, your usage of kmeans is wrong. The pixel coordinates should play no role in the clustering. You should only hand the color triplets to kmeans.

```
sample = cvCreateMat( image->height*image->width, 3, CV_32FC1 );
```

…

```
                  for(j=0;j<image->width;j++)
                      {
                        b = data[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels +0];
                        g = data[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels +1];
                        r = data[i*image->widthStep + j*image->nChannels +2];
                        cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 0, b);
                        cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 1, g);
                        cvSetReal2D( sample, k, 2, r);
                        k++;
                      }
```

Then you also have an indexing bug further down the road when setting data.